# PGP version GnuPG v2 vs. GnuPG v2.0.22 (MingW32)

Tags: mingw32, pgp, gnupg

I don't really know if stackoverflow is the right place to ask but I'll try. I know people here sit on a lot of knownledge! I downloaded and installed Gpg4win 2.2.2 (I installed the GPA package). Opened up Kleopatra and generated a key. When I exported the public key I noticed this

Version: GnuPG v2

I've never seen anyone with just "GnuPG v2" as version. What I want is "Version: GnuPG v2.0.22 (MingW32)" or an explanation.

Am I missing MingW32 packages or what? I googled MingW32 and found an installer and installed all the basic packages. Rebooted my computer and generated a new key, still just "GnuPG v2".

So what am I missing? Does it even matter? It feels more secure to have GnuPG+MingW32 than just GnuPG.

Best regards Adam

Comment: Yes, it is the wrong location. I voted to migrate your question to Super User, where it belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GnuPG vs GnuPG 2 was already discussed often, for example there is an [explanation in this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/655246/are-gnupg-and-gnupg2-compatible-with-each-other). GnuPG 2's manual pages (`man gpg2` on unix systems) has following explanation:

> In contrast to the standalone version `gpg`, which is more suited for server and embedded platforms, this version is commonly installed under the name `gpg2` and more targeted to the desktop as it requires several other modules to be installed.

[MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) is just a kind of compatibility framework for porting applications developed for unix-like systems to Windows (as there are different programming models and interfaces for example file access). As end user, MinGW or not MinGW does not matter to you; the actual GnuPG code is the same. You do not have to install the MinGW components on your own either; the [GnuPG installer for Windows](http://gpg4win.org/) brings everything you need.